# How to get a custom address attribute value in magento order shipping address?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have a custom address attribute. In the backend, order page i need to get that attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
$orderId = '100000001';

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$customAttributeValue = $order->getShippingAddress()->getAttributeText('your_custom_attribute');
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. Thanx any way Amith.

Comment: Fixed it with another way.

Comment: That's good, so you should post your solutions here for anyone else have the same problem.

Comment: Your answer is correct an it helps. What i meant earlier was i wanted the attribute value to do something else. and i have done it by another approach. Thanks.